# I am looking for an efficient solution to combine two collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a database in MongoDB with two collections:

Collection1:

```
{
    "id": "675",
    "material_category_id": "35",
    "material_name": "name",
    "material_original_name": "Name",
    "material_other_names": "",
    "material_description": "Stuff about material",
    "material_online_id": null,
    "material_country_of_origin": "243",
    "main_color": "9",
    "page_title": "Page Title",
    "pattern": "0",
    "last_update": "2015-06-22 13:59:47"
  }
```

Collection2:

```
{
    "id": "3852",
    "material_id": "675",
    "material_photo_name": "stuff.jpg",
    "original_name": "otherstuff.jpg",
    "visible": "1",
    "uploaded_at": "2015-11-16 05:27:00",
    "thumb": "0"
  }
```

I need to transfer "material_photo_name" from collection2 into collection1 for each appropriate document (material_id in collection2 matches id in collection1)... Is there a way to do this without manually rewriting the database? Thousands upon thousands of documents in collection2 and hundreds in collection1...
NOTE: each value will be unique, so a simple update() will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write a migration script.

You can easily do it using the [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/client/). It would look something like this:

```
mongo
use yourDB
db.Collection1.find().forEach(function(doc1){
  var doc2 = db.Collection2.findOne({material_id: doc1.id});
  doc1.material_photo_name = doc2.material_photo_name;
  db.Collection1.save(doc1);
});
```

If this task is a part of a development project, it would be advisable to use a migration framework (e.g. [mongo-migrate](https://github.com/afloyd/mongo-migrate)). There are migration frameworks for a variety of languages.